# Clang warns about potential memory leak when constructor involves recursion

Tags: c++

I am writing a class where recursion is a must when writing its constructor, then clang analyzer complains about potential memory leak of this function, although I cannot see why and can guarantee that the recursion will always terminate.

Here is the code:

```cpp
VeblenNormalForm::VeblenNormalForm(CantorNormalForm* _cnf) {
    terms = vnf_terms();
    _is_cnf = true;

    if (!_cnf->is_zero()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _cnf->terms.size(); i++) {
            terms.push_back(
                phi(&ZERO, new VeblenNormalForm(get<0>(_cnf->terms[i]))) * get<1>(_cnf->terms[i])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The analysis given by clang is that it tries to enter the true branch for a few times and then claims there exist a potential memory leakage. Is it a real warning or just clang analyzer doing weird things?

Comment: What exactly is the warning you get? Also, what C++ version are you using?

Comment: a memory leak is not where you `new` but in all the rest of the code that doesn't delete. Can you post a [mcve] ?

Comment: We cannot know if there is a memory leak if you share the `new` call but not the corresponding `delete` call elsewhere

Comment: What is `ZERO`? What is `phi` and what does it do?

Comment: The warning is `Potential memory leak (clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks)`. If you mean c++ standard then I believe i am not using grammar above c++11 standards, and if you mean clang version then it is 6.0.0.

Comment: Avoid owning raw pointers and `new`. shared/unique_ptr should be used instead.

Comment: I really do not mean that the memory leak happened, but the warning of potential memory leak is given by clang, so there is no minimal reproducible example of memory leak here. `ZERO` is a `VeblenNormalForm*` object and `phi` is just an alias of `std::tuple<VeblenNormalForm*, VeblenNormalForm*>`.

Comment: Also this is a constructor, and these pointers given by `new` is stored in the object so by no means i will delete them inside the constructor. Also, these pointers will be usually shared by multiple objects so delete them in the destructor will also make program malfunction so i will not delete them there.

Comment: If any `terms.push_back` throws, previous `new VeblenNormalForm` would leak.

Comment: @core_exe, wait, if you don't delete them in the destructor, how do you expect there to be no memory leaks?

Comment: That is why i am confused. Deleting them in the destructor will make the other objects storing the pointer malfunction, but not deleting them will lead to memory leakage. Is there a standard way to resolve this kind of problems?

Comment: Read up on `std::shared_ptr` if you need such a shared ownership. But do yourself a favor and start with `std::shared_ptr<const VeblenNormalForm>`. If you also have shared mutability, good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is with exception safety. Your `terms` vector stores tuples of `VeblenNormalForm*`, which you allocate at least the second element with `new`.

Presumably you have corresponding `delete`s in your destructor, but if an exception is thrown from a constructor, the destructor will not be called.

In your case, you could allocate the first N elements correctly, but get an exception in N + 1st element. In that case, your first N elements will be leaked. `terms` will still get destructed properly, but since you only have raw pointers in it, nothing will be deleted properly.

You could fix this issue by making your tuple be a `std::tuple<VeblenNormalForm*, std::shared_ptr<const VeblenNormalForm>>`. In this case, even if you get an exception mid-construction, the smart pointers will correctly delete the well-constructed objects. This assumes the first pointer is pointing to some global variable, so it's still just a regular pointer. If that is also being dynamically allocated, you need to use a smart pointer for that as well.

Code-wise, it should look like this:

```
using phi = std::tuple<VeblenNormalForm*, std::shared_ptr<const VeblenNormalForm>>;

VeblenNormalForm::VeblenNormalForm(CantorNormalForm* _cnf) {
    terms = vnf_terms();
    _is_cnf = true;

    if (!_cnf->is_zero()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _cnf->terms.size(); i++) {
            terms.push_back(
                phi(&ZERO, std::make_shared<VeblenNormalForm>(get<0>(_cnf->terms[i]))) * get<1>(_cnf->terms[i])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Note that these pointers point to `const VeblenNormalForm`. Sharing mutable data across different objects is very difficult to get right. If you can prove to yourself you will do it right, feel free to remove the `const`.

Comment: These pointers will potentially be stored in multiple objects. Deleting them in the destructor will make the other objects storing the pointer malfunction, but not deleting them will lead to memory leakage. Is there a standard way to resolve this kind of problems?